# Swift protocol specializing generic protocol

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols, specialization

Is it possible to have a protocol that specializes a generic protocol? I want something like this:

```
protocol Protocol: RawRepresentable {
  typealias RawValue = Int
  ...
}
```

This does compile, but when I try to access the `init` or `rawValue` from a Protocol instance, its type is `RawValue` instead of `Int`.

Comment: You're trying to create a protocol that's only applicable to enums with an `Int` raw value?

Comment: Can’t you find a better name for your protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 4, you can add constraints to your protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol: RawRepresentable where RawValue == Int {
}
```

And now all methods defined on MyProtocol will have an Int rawValue. For example:

```
extension MyProtocol {
    var asInt: Int {
        return rawValue
    }
}

enum Number: Int, MyProtocol {
    case zero
    case one
    case two
}

print(Number.one.asInt)
// prints 1
```

Types that adopt RawRepresentable but whose RawValue is not Int can not adopt your constrained protocol:

```
enum Names: String {
    case arthur
    case barbara
    case craig
}

// Compiler error
extension Names : MyProtocol { }
```